# Only list and libraries are viewable to to other users. The web parts are not visible to other viewers

Tags: web-part

I have full control.  I have approved an published all items and none are checked out to me.  There are no pending actions for others to approve any content.  Other users can add web parts with the same approval.  I have deleted and re added the web parts with no change.  I am not in a personal view.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the pages and sites are also published.
If you see a yellow bar under your navigation that says something like this: "Status: Checked in and viewable by authorized users.  "
This means that your site/page is not properly published. You have to click on the "Publish" tab as shown below:

[image]

After you click Publish, the yellow bar should disappear and the web page and content should be visible to all users.

Also, be sure that you are not using "Target Audience" to a specific group that will exclude main users. Check the "Target Audience" column by clicking "Edit Webpart" on any webpart that is hidden >> Advanced >> Target Audience.

Hope this helps.